# Import module from subfolder

Tags: python, import, module, subdirectory

I want to import subfolders as modules. Therefore every subfolder contains a `__init__.py`. My folder structure is like this:

```
src\
  main.py
  dirFoo\
    __init__.py
    foofactory.py
    dirFoo1\
      __init__.py
      foo1.py
    dirFoo2\
      __init__.py
      foo2.py
```

In my main script I import

```
from dirFoo.foofactory import FooFactory
```

In this factory file I include the sub modules:

```
from dirFoo1.foo1 import Foo1
from dirFoo2.foo2 import Foo2
```

If I call my foofactory I get the error, that python can't import the submodules foo1 and foo2:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tmp/src/main.py", line 1, in <module>
from dirFoo.foofactory import FooFactory
  File "/Users/tmp/src/dirFoo/foofactory.py", line 1, in    <module>
from dirFoo1.foo1 import Foo1
    ImportError: No module named dirFoo1.foo1
```

Answer (score 193, accepted):

There's no need to mess with your `PYTHONPATH` or `sys.path` here.

To properly use absolute imports in a package you should include the "root" packagename as well, e.g.:

```
from dirFoo.dirFoo1.foo1 import Foo1
from dirFoo.dirFoo2.foo2 import Foo2
```

Or you can use [relative imports](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references):

```
from .dirfoo1.foo1 import Foo1
from .dirfoo2.foo2 import Foo2
```

Comment: One thing to remember! add `__init__.py` to every subfolder you are importing from.

Comment: Empty `__init__.py` may do the job.

Comment: What would the syntax be if previously `Foo1` was in the parent directory and one coded something like `from Foo1 import *`. Is there a way to achieve that same effect so you don't have to prefix everything with `Foo1`?

Comment: @AzizAlto: without your comment this solution is not very useful

Comment: Using `from .dirfoo1.foo1 import Foo1` etc. worked for me.  Also, rather than empty dunder init files, I had these two lines: `import site` followed by `site.addsitedir('./')`

Comment: @AzizAlto Depending on the use case, `__init__.py` is no longer needed with Python 3.3+ (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37140173/1340631).

Answer (score 30):

Just to notify here. (from a newbee, keviv22)

**Never and ever for the sake of your own good, name the folders or files with symbols like "-" or "_". If you did so, you may face few issues. like mine, say, though your command for importing is correct, you wont be able to successfully import the desired files which are available inside such named folders.**

Invalid Folder namings as follows:

- Generic-Classes-Folder
- Generic_Classes_Folder

valid Folder namings for above:

- GenericClassesFolder or Genericclassesfolder or genericClassesFolder (or like this without any spaces or special symbols among the words)

What mistake I did:

consider the file structure.

```
Parent
   . __init__.py
   . Setup
     .. __init__.py
     .. Generic-Class-Folder
        ... __init__.py
        ... targetClass.py
   . Check
     .. __init__.py
     .. testFile.py
```

What I wanted to do?

- from testFile.py, I wanted to import the 'targetClass.py' file inside the Generic-Class-Folder file to use the function named "functionExecute" in 'targetClass.py' file

What command I did?

- from 'testFile.py', wrote command, 
    `from Core.Generic-Class-Folder.targetClass import functionExecute`
- Got errors like `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Tried many searches and viewed many stackoverflow questions and unable to decide what went wrong. I cross checked my files multiple times, i used `__init__.py` file, inserted environment path and hugely worried what went wrong......

And after a long long long time, i figured this out while talking with a friend of mine. I am little stupid to use such naming conventions. I should never use space or special symbols to define a name for any folder or file. So, this is what I wanted to convey. Have a good day!

(sorry for the huge post over this... just letting my frustrations go.... :) Thanks!)

Comment: Spaces and dashes ("-") would cause this, but underscores ("_") should still work fine.

Answer (score 11):

Set your PYTHONPATH environment variable. For example like this PYTHONPATH=.:.. (for *nix family).

Also you can manually add your current directory (src in your case) to pythonpath:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd())
```

Answer (score 7):

Say your project is structured this way:

```
+---MyPythonProject
|   +---.gitignore
|   +---run.py
|   |   +---subscripts
|   |   |   +---script_one.py
|   |   |   +---script_two.py
```

Inside `run.py`, you can import scripts one and two by:

```
from subscripts import script_one as One
from subscripts import script_two as Two
```

Now, still inside `run.py`, you'll be able to call their methods with:

```
One.method_from_one(param)
Two.method_from_two(other_param)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just create an empty `__init__.py` file and add it in root as well as all the sub directory/folder of your python application where you have other python modules. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages