# Python imports from subfolders

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I am attempting to grade some python submissions that are in separate folders for each student.  To do this, there is a function, say f() which I want to run.  I understand that if my current path is the same as the one where the file is located, I can simply do

```
import filename
filename.f()
```

However, are there better ways?  For instance, let's say the directory structure is as follows:

```
main.py
student/run_this.py
```

I know that if there is a "__init__.py" file in the student folder, I can just type

```
import student.run_this
```

However, without that file, it doesn't work.

Some similar questions I found were

- [Import module from subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953844/import-module-from-subfolder)
- [How to do relative imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python)
- http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/192000/import-from-a-subdirectory-of-a-directory-on-pythonpath

but none of these gave particularly satisfying answers.

Comment: So what exactly is your issue with the `__init__.py` file?

Comment: You add the `student` folder to your path, then import `run_this`. That's what the other answers tell you to do, what did you try that didn't work?

Comment: It's not that it didn't work as much as it didn't seem elegant.  Or at least, adding \__init__.py's seems pretty offputting to me - it seems immoral to modify the file structure to access subfolders.

For changing the path, I read that was bad practice, but it does seem like a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

create an `__init__.py` module inside the folder `student` which should contain

```
from . import *
```

You can then call any modules from student folder to its parent folder modules as

```
import student.module.py
```

If you post any other errors you are facing, we can help further.

Comment: Do you think you could explain (or link me to material) explaining why \__init__.py's are required? That did end up working, but I'm a bit confused about what the design logic is

Comment: \_\_init__.py is just as simple as class inheritance logic in c++ or python. When the python looks at a folder it does not includes all the modules available in it. If u specify the functions to be done when python enter into a class at \_\_init__ function, it understands well. here we are just importing the necessary or all modules when python encounters a folder using \_\_init__.

Comment: This answer is the only one that I could find to answer the problem that I had, thanks @MathanKumar !