# Importing a class from one directory to another directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I have two different directories:

```
/dir1
    file.py  
/dir2
    /dir2.1
        file.py
```

I need to import `file.py` from `dir1` into to the file of `dir2.1`. Can anyone give an idea?

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html?

Comment: This question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953844/import-module-from-subfolder

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `__init__.py`

from the docs:

> The **init**.py files are required to make Python treat the
>   directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent
>   directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally
>   hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In
>   the simplest case, **init**.py can just be an empty file, but it can
>   also execute initialization code for the package or set the **all**
>   variable, described later.

Make your file structure:

```
files
    dir1
        __init__.py
        file.py
    dir2
        dir2.1
            file.py
    init__.py
```

then at `files\dir2\dir2.1\file.py`:

```
import files.dir1.file
```