# Create a python package & install it as source distribution and not a .egg?

Tags: python, package, installation, setup.py, sdist

I have a python package which has several data files in a `data` folder which have to be read when the package is used; these are not python scripts. However when I install my package to test it with `python setup.py install --user` only an `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-package/mypackage-1.0.0-py2.7.egg` is installed and so the code can't read the `data` directory.

I see other packages like `numpy` install with a `*.dist-info` and a `numpy` folder.

How do I make my package install like that?

Comment: Isn't the whole idea of subfolders that they are not installed directly but need to be imported like `import mypackage.data.whatever`? Here is a question about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953844/import-module-from-subfolder or you can refer to the [`module documentation`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

Comment: That has nothing to do with 'How do I make my package install like that?' And what is the point of `MANIFEST.in` or a `include_package_data` in `setuptools.setup` if I'm meant to just use the method you described?

Comment: As I understand it, `include_package_data` is meant to be used for non-python files like readme, docs, raw data, images etc. This is at least what I get from the [python-packaging docs](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/non-code-files.html).

Comment: Exactly. When did I say I wanted to execute a script? I'll update my question for clarity.

Comment: Ok, that was a missing piece of information, maybe it was my mistake. Anyways, so did you try to use a `MANIFEST.in`, specify your data files in it, like `include data/*.*` and finally `include_package_data=True` in setuptools? What do you actually mean by "and so the code can't read the data directory."? Why shouldn't it read the data directory? Doesn't that depend on the code and not on the installation?

Comment: "did you try to ...specify your data files" Yes.
"What do you actually mean" Literally what I said, that file/folder doesn't exist in an egg, so it cannot read it.
"Why shouldn't it read the data directory" Because an egg is a file and not a directory.

Rather, the data + files do exist in the .egg format, but they have to be read with pkg_resources module which isn't suitable. This is about how to install a package with a source directory and a `*.dist-info` inside `*site-packages`, nothing else.

Comment: So, did you use `zip_safe = False` and still get only the egg-file and no extracted version of it in the site-packages folder?  If you really want to get dist-info then you need to use wheels instead of eggs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
python setup.py sdist
pip install dist/*.tar.gz --user
```

`sdist` creates a Source Archine as a tar.gz inside `dist/`. `pip` then installs it to the users site-packages directory.

[More info here.](https://packaging.python.org/glossary/#term-source-distribution-or-sdist)