# Import module error

Tags: python

I have the following file structure:

[image: file_system]

And I don't know why this piece of code doesn't work:

```
# this is in main.py
import sys
from pathlib import Path

main = Path(__file__).parents[2]
if main not in sys.path:
        sys.path.insert(0, main)
print(main)
from mainFolder.dir1.subdir1 import forImport
```

Comparing it to this [Import module from subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953844/import-module-from-subfolder) I can't explain myself what I am doing wrong.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your main.py is within a subfolder, the import statement doesn't search "siblings" of that folder, only scripts in the folder where main.py is and subfolders in the same folder

if your main.py was in the folder *above* mainFolder your statement would work