# Getting error when importing from sibling package

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-import, subdirectory, siblings

I am learning django, following on "Tango with Django"

My project structure is as follows:

```
/django_demo
|-- __init__.py
|-- manage.py
|-- populate.py
|-- settings.py
|.....<other modules>
|
|--/django_demo
|  |-- __init__.py
|  |-- populate_rango.py
|  |...<other modules>
|
|--/rango
|  |-- __init__.py
|  |-- models.py
|  |-- apps.py
|  |....<other modules>
```

I am not able to resolve two queries:

**Query 1 -**

`populate_rango.py` contains the following code:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'django_demo.settings')

import django
django.setup()

from django_demo.rango import models
```

the `models` import is giving `unresolved import` error, even though I am using the correct [absolute imports](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) notation, acc. to the documentation, and similar questions on [sibling package imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953844/import-module-from-subfolder) as well as [here][3]

**Query 2 -**

the `populate.py` under the root `/django-demo` package contains the following code:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'django_demo.settings')

import django
django.setup()

from rango import models
```

from the documentation, it is mandatory to either use the [absolute imports](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) or the **dotted notation** to import from sub-folder.

the above piece of code uses neither. I am not able to understand how does the

```
from rango import models
```

doesn't throw an unresolved import error.

note 1 : I have already my appname included in the `INSTALLED_APPS` under `\django_demo\settings.py` as

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rango.apps.RangoConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles', ]
```

the `\rango\apps.py` has the `RangoConfig` class:

```
class RangoConfig(AppConfig):
name = 'rango'
```

Note 2: 
 1. all my `__init__.py` files are empty

2. I am using virtualenv with python 3.5.2 as an interpreter on pydev+eclipse oxygen on Ubuntu

**UPDATE-1**

As seen in the traceback below, it is the `django.setup()`which is giving a runtime error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sat/coding/python_dev/oxygen_workspace/django_demo/django_demo/populate_rango.py", line 10, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "/home/sat/coding/flask_dev/venv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 22, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/home/sat/coding/flask_dev/venv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/sat/coding/flask_dev/venv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/sat/coding/flask_dev/venv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 110, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/home/sat/coding/flask_dev/venv3/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'django_demo'
```

I do not understand the reason for this.

**UPDATE-2**

i created a new django project named **new_django** on similar lines, and the `from rango import models` is working fine in that.

**new_django** structure:

```
/new_django
|-- __init__.py
|-- manage.py
|-- populate.py
|-- settings.py
|.....<other modules>
|
|--/new_django
|  |-- __init__.py
|  |-- populate_rango.py
|  |...<other modules>
|
|--/rango
|  |-- __init__.py
|  |-- models.py
|  |-- apps.py
|  |....<other modules>
```

the `populate_rango.py` contains the following code:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'new_django.settings')

import django
django.setup()

from rango.models import
```

this terminates without any error when run.

the `settings.py` and `rango/apps.py` for **new_django** project have identical code as their **django_demo** counterparts.

When, however, I use the **absolute import** like `from new_django.rango import models`, to refer to the hierarchy `new_django/rango` as mentioned in  documentation, I get the traceback below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sat/coding/python_dev/oxygen_workspace/new_django/new_django/populate_rango.py", line 12, in <module>
    from new_django.rango import models
ImportError: No module named 'new_django.rango'
```

this also happens in case of **relative import** - `from ..rango import models`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sat/coding/python_dev/oxygen_workspace/new_django/new_django/populate_rango.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ..rango import models
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

Could someone please explain why:

1. in **UPDATE-1**,`django.setup()` is giving error?
2. in **UPDATE-2**, the import `from rango import models` is not giving an error, while absolute and relative imports are?

Answer (score 0):

Since the Django version is 1.11 which you are using and having manage.py file inside the django_demo project the project directory is loaded in the path variable visible for any imports here on.

**Query 2**
It is running fine because the rango module which is present in the scope of the parent django_demo i.e. project folder loaded in the PATH.
**Query 1**
It is showing import error since you have 2 module with same name django_demo causing double import problem See [here](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html).
So to solve this move your manage.py outside the parent project directory django_demo. This way your relative import will work smoothly as same name module will not conflict anymore.

```
|-- manage.py
/django_demo
    |-- __init__.py

    |-- populate.py
    |-- settings.py
    |.....<other modules>
    |
    |--/django_demo
    |  |-- __init__.py
    |  |-- populate_rango.py
    |  |...<other modules>
    |
    |--/rango
    |  |-- __init__.py
    |  |-- models.py
    |  |-- apps.py
    |  |....<other modules>
```

Now we can import `models.py` file from `rango` module  which is one level outside the parent directory in populate_rango.py file by

```
from django_demo.rango import models
```

Comment: this is not how I named it, it is a standard practice followed in a Django project, to have a **parent folder**  containing the *project* (of the same name)  as well as the all the *app* folders.


I only added  an `__init__.py` for the parent `/django_new` folder, to avoid the `not a package` error while importing, so as to focus on the `import` error at hand

Comment: @satvik.t Could you please tell the dango package version in use.

Comment: it is Django 1.11, python 3.5.2

Comment: @satvik.t You have a double import problem because of the version of django you are using is  < 1.4