# Avoid to import the path when using subfolders in python

Tags: python, testing, path, directory, subdirectory

Previously I was working without unittests and I had this structure for my project:

```
-main.py
   -folderFunctions:
       -functionA.py
```

Just using init file in folderFunctions, and importing

```
 from folderFunctions import functionA
```

everything was working good.

Now I have also unittests wihch I organized in this way:

```
-main.py
-folderFunctions:
    -functionA.py
    -folderTest:
       -testFunctionA.py
```

So I had to add (in order to run testFunctionA.py) in both functionA.py and testFunctionA.py these 2 lines to import the path:

```
 myPath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
 sys.path.insert(0, myPath + '../..')
```

In this way the test works properly. 
But it is ugly to me and I guess also not very pythonic.
Is there a way to make it more elegant?

Comment: Create a folder called `tests` on the same level where `main.py` is and put all your tests in there.

Comment: @orangelnk I read that usually the testfolder is at the same level of the functions one or on a deeper lever. Is on main level still pythonic?

Comment: I have to admit that I'm far from an expert when it comes to packaging but 99% of the time when I look at a package I see a `tests` folder at the same level where `setup.py` is located (meaning 1 level above all of the actual code).

Answer (score 1):

If you want your library/application to become bigger and easy to package I hardly recommend to separate source code from test code, because test code shouldn't be packaged in binary distributions (egg or wheel).

You can follow this tree structure:

```
+-- src/
|    +-- main.py
|    \-- folder_functions/  # <- Python package
|        +-- __init__.py
|        \-- function_a.py
\-- tests/
    \-- folder_functions/
        +-- __init__.py
        \-- test_function_a.py
```

Note: according to the [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), Python packages and modules names should be in "snake case" (lowercase + underscore).

The **src** directory could be avoided if you have (and you should) a main package.

As explained in other comments, the **setup.p**y file should stand next to the **src** and **tests** folders (root level).

Read the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org)

**edit**

The next step is to create a **setup.py**, for instance:

```
from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='Your-App',
    version='0.1.0',
    author='Your Name',
    author_email='your@email',
    url='URL of your project home page',
    description="one line description",
    long_description='long description ',
    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 4 - Beta',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: Python Software Foundation License',
        'Operating System :: MacOS :: MacOS X',
        'Operating System :: Microsoft :: Windows',
        'Operating System :: POSIX',
        'Programming Language :: Python',
        'Topic :: Software Development',
    ],
    platforms=["Linux", "Windows", "OS X"],
    license="MIT License",
    keywords="keywords",
    packages=find_packages("src"),
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'cmd_name = main:main',
        ],
    })
```

Once your project is configured, you can create a virtualenv and install your application inside:

```
virtualenv your-app
source your-app/bin/activate
pip install -e .
```

You can run your tests with unitests standard module.

To import your module in your **test_function_a.py**, just proceed as usual:

```
from folder_functions import function_a
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! so with this tree structure, how could I import in test_function_a.py function_a.py?

Answer (score 0):

The more elegant way is `from folderFunctions.folderTest import testFunctionA` and make sure that you have an `__init__.py` file in the `folderTest` directory. You may also look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953844/import-module-from-subfolder)