# Python Relative Imports "Above Top Level"

Tags: python, django, anaconda

This is my directory structure

```
src\
  dirCode\
    dirSubCode\
      test.py
  Django\
    DjangoApp\
      Home\
       views.py
```

From within views.py I'm trying to import a class (let's call it Main) from test.py.  The line in test.py is simply

```
from dirCode.dirSubCode.test import Main
```

and I'm getting a ModuleNotFoundError when I try to run the server.  I printed out the os.sys.path and the second entry points to 'src\' while the first entry is simply ''.  Since this is not the only app from where I'm going to need to call "external" code I'm trying to avoid hard-coding

```
sys.path.insert(0,'path\to\src\dirCode\dirSubCode\')
```

if that would even work.  I've tried looking through documentation, looking at other StackOverflow questions ([Import module from subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953844/import-module-from-subfolder)), etc. but I'm at a loss as to how to do this.  I've tried going into the src\Django\DjangoApp\Home directory and just running a python console and simply trying to import the class but it's giving me the same error.

One odd development that I'm running into is that when I try to run it from the Anaconda Prompt (yes, I'm running Windows) it doesn't work but when I run the file in PyCharm it does work.  If that helps provide some insight as to what might be going on I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: You can't do a relative import from a module that's not inside the same package. It has to be an absolute import. However, your import *is* absolute, not relative. Learn about the search path (what it does, what it's default is, how to control it in PyCharm), and don't modify it at runtime (inside a script). Or just put everything in the same package if it really belongs in one. Also, are any of those packages? You don't mention any `__init__.py` files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to do this is to introduce a shared package that you can install into a virtualenv for each webapp. Either from an actual release, or by using

> python setup.py develop

Form within the shared package you essentially create a symlink in the venv that allows you to just import.

A more modern and simpler version is

> pip install -e .

inside the library. See [Python setup.py develop vs install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048732/python-setup-py-develop-vs-install)

Comment: Although I'm not using setup.py develop, this lead me to find this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048732/python-setup-py-develop-vs-install which lead to the ultimate answer of using pip install -e path/to/package

Comment: Neat! Didn’t know that existed, will use it myself.

Comment: Augmented my answer so your comment is more visible.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to set the `PYTHONPATH` variable, which is used to set the default search path for modules.

https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH

As per the python docs the syntax is like so...

https://docs.python.org/3.6/using/windows.html#excursus-setting-environment-variables

> To temporarily set environment variables, open Command Prompt and use the set command:
>
> ```
> C:\>set PATH=C:\Program Files\Python 3.6;%PATH%
> C:\>set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\My_python_lib
> C:\>python
> ```

Pycharm- in the Run/Debug configuration- sets it when you have it checked off (which is the default).

[image: pycharm image]