# with __init__.py import start from root, why still No mudule in subfolder Python 3

Tags: python

I want to import .py in a subfolder from a .py in another subfolder. I have learned
 [you should add **init**.py in subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260792/import-a-file-from-a-subdirectory) and [you should include your root path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953844/import-module-from-subfolder)

here is my forlder structure :

```
pycharm_project_973
    __init__.py
    /slic
        multi_slic.py
        __init__.py
    /muilti
        main_unet_up4.py
        __init__.py
```

[image: my directory, just to make sure. Is it correct with stupid mistake?]
here is some  import code I tried in main_unet_up4.py :

```
from pycharm_project_973.slic.multi_slic import  multi_slic as multi_slic
from pycharm_project_973.slic.multi_slic import DataGenerator as DG
import pycharm_project_973
```

each time and I got :

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycharm_project_973'

then I tried:

```
import slic
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'slic'

```
from slic.multi_slic import DataGenerator as DG
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'slic'

```
import slic.multi_slic
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'slic'

I am using anaconda virtual environment and tmux. This folder is a pycharm promote project location in server. I use `mark directory as source root` in pycharm and it worked well then I tried to work on server it remind me this `No module` issue.

Please help, thanks!

edit after the comment I tried to use:

```
 from ..model import multi_net
```

I got

> ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

```
sys.path.append("..")
from model import multi_unet
```

It worked well.
I guess it is because that the root dir has been added to my system lib search list.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054271/how-to-import-a-python-class-that-is-in-a-directory-above) for referencing in a relative path that is above the current directory

Comment: @AlexW I solved it, thank you. Now I need to figure out how it work, the whole path and module system . Thank you again.