# Importing python modules from root folder

Tags: python, python-import

I am using python 2.7 and have the following project structure

```
main-folder

    --folder1
        - script.py

    --folder2
        - scr.py

    -- abc.py
    -- util.py
```

I am trying to import abc.py into util.py using

```
from main-folder import abc
```

but I am not getting error as below

```
ImportError: No module named main-folder
```

I also tried to append the path to main-folder to the path using

```
sys.path.append(r'path/to main-folder/main-folder')
```

I also have *init*.py in main-folder , folder1 & folder2

Comment: Try putting an empty file called `__init__.py` into each of `main-folder`, `folder1`, and `folder2`.

Comment: I have them already

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import module from subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953844/import-module-from-subfolder)

Comment: Make sure the init file is named as  `__init__.py`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll assume your package is not actually called `main-folder` because that's a syntax error.

- `sys.path` / `PYTHONPATH` is where Python *looks for* modules, so adding a folder to sys.path means what's *in* it can be imported (as a top-level module), it doesn't make the folder itself importable
- when you run a script as a Python file, Python adds *that file's folder* on the PYTHONPATH e.g. here if you run main-folder/folder1/script.py, `main-folder/folder1` is what's on your PYTHONPATH, and that obviously can't access abc or utils no matter how you slice it
- `import <foo>` or `from <foo> import <bar>` is an *absolute import*, it starts its search from the PYTHONPATH[0]
- you can specify PYTHONPATH on the command line, e.g. `PYTHONPATH=. python main-folder/folder1/script.py will *also* add whatever` .` is to your PYTHONPATH, which may be what you want?
- within a pacakge (a directory with an `__init__` and a bunch of submodules), it's probably better to use relative imports e.g. `util` should use `from . import abc` if they're supposed to be sibling submodules of the same package

[0] that's not actually true for Python 2, as [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) necessarily had to keep the old behaviour working but you probably want to assume it regardless, you can "opt out" of the old behaviour by using the `__future__` stanza listed in the PEP