# How to import functions from script as package from same-level folder

Tags: python, import, init

I have the following folder structure:

```
[parent_folder]
    |-- [main_folder]
            |-- main.py
    |-- [functions_folder]
            |-- module_functions.py
            |-- init.py
```

File contents:

```
#main.py
from functions_folder.module_functions import function_a
function_a(5)

#module_functions.py
def function_a(inp):
    print(inp)

#init.py
from .functions_folder import module_functions
```

At it's current state, `main` cannot load functions from `functions_folder` (which makes sense) with the error:

```
[...]
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'functions_folder'
```

-I know for fact that if `main.py` was in `parent_folder` the entire thing would run without problems (because it would be able to see one level down).

-I also know that if I add:

```
sys.path.append(re.search(r'(.*\\)', os.path.dirname(__file__)).group(1))
```

to `main.py` before importing (ie. if I add the `parent_folder` to path so that it can now see the `functions_folder` one level down), it would again be ok.
But, is there way to achieve this without adding to path, just by using `init`s?

In other words, what would the content of the two `init` files in the `parent_folder` and `main_folder` need to be in order for `main` to see the `functions_folder` content?

EDIT. I believe that the question suggested in comments does not answer the current one because the problem is with imports from same level (but different folder) or higher, not from a folder down.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import module from subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953844/import-module-from-subfolder)

Comment: @Saif Asif I believe that it does not because in this case the imports are from folders below the level of `main`. But if I am thick and it can be easily inferred from this post what is the solution in my case, I would appreciate if you posted the answer.