# Access function in other python file within a subfolder

Tags: python, function, file

I am building a fairly complex python app with various scripts. I am planning on sorting these scripts into subfolders so I can then access the functions from a main file. For example having a function called `main` inside a file called `test.py` inside a subfolder called `test`. How would I call the function?

I have tried using

`from test import main`

However I get a `ModuleNotFoundError` error.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Missed the `__init__.py`? And it would be `from test.test import main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953844/import-module-from-subfolder), to import files from subfolders in python, use the '.' to signify a subdirectory.

- In your example, the import would be

`from test.test import main`

- The general syntax for such an import would be the following:

`from [subfolderName].[fileName] import [functionName]`

- To import all functions from file, the syntax would be:

`import [subfolderName].[fileName]`