# Python: How to move/rename a module without changing dependencies

Tags: python, python-import

I have following file structure:

```
proj
- __init__.py
- bar.py  # contains constant 'foo', used in consumers of proj
```

Now I have realised `bar.py` fits nicely in a subfolder. However I need to make this change without changing the code depending on `proj`. Specifically, `from proj.bar import foo` should still work. So I'm changing the file structure to:

```
proj
- __init__.py
- subfolder
- - bar.py
```

I have tried to put `from .subfolder import bar` into `__init__.py`.  However, following error occurs:

```py
import proj
print(proj.bar)  # <module 'proj.subfolder.bar' from '~/proj/subfolder/bar.py'>

from proj.bar import foo  # ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'proj.bar'
```

What can I put in `__init__.py` of proj such that any consumer can still do `from proj.bar import foo`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import module from subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953844/import-module-from-subfolder)

Comment: No it doesn't - I don't have a subfolder with same name as the module.

Comment: so you are saying there is no way to do this? what if I'm grouping multiple modules.

Comment: Just to make this explicit: I want to group modules, not turn one module in a subpackage. But I hear you, this might not be possible.